# Modally presented view controllers lifecycle

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

So Im struggling understanding this. Im pretty new to iOS development so bear with me here.

Im making an app that does not use storyboards or segues. Im creating my view controllers programmatically and presenting them modally (I don' really know if it is the best way).

For some VC, the modal presentation is fine, since I want to present them over the current VC and I want the presenter VC to show underneath.

Now there are other VCs that Im also presenting modally, altough I don't benefit from the modal presentation at all, but since Im used to it Im doing it this way.

The problem I have is that for example:
I go from VC1-->VC2, but I want VC1 to be deallocated, and it doesnt. After a few VC transitions, lets say VC1-->VC2-->VC3--VC2 (this is a new instance of VC2), the memory used keeps increasing, and the dealloc method for any of these VCs is not being called.

Calling `[self.presenterviewcontroller dismiss]` on the presented VC has no effect, since the presenter is nil when I check it on an NSLog.

So my question is how do I get rid of some presenter VCs that I dont need to prevent memory allocation from growing. (Sometimes it hits 260MB of usage).